# Which cloud based CI/ build server to use with .net

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, hosting, build-automation

We are a very small company but I'd like to setup a continuous integration server. We often work remotely with our code stored in BitBucket. I'd like each commit to build and deploy to a staging site on the web server. I don't really want to install the CI server on the web server as I want to use the CI server for multiple projects and server.

Can anyone recommend a hosted/ cloud based CI server that can build and deploy .NET code to a remote server. The only one I've come across so far is Bamboo. This will cost $20/month which isn't a lot but it's a bit more than I was looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: $20 is too much?  What number are you looking for?

Comment: $20 isn't a lot, but I suppose I was hoping for something Pay As You Go or free. Equally if it's $20 or more then so be it, but I wondered if anyone had any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudbees has Jenkins On Demand, competes in same space as Bamboo.

You are way way way better off running a CI environment locally than "in the cloud" Bamboo/Jenkins(Hudson)/TeamCity or even Microsoft TFS will do what you want.

Comment: "You are way way way better off running a CI environment locally than "in the cloud". Care the explain why?